# Enlarging multiple images with hover over

Tags: c#, silverlight, hover, image-enlarge

So I am trying to enlarge an image with hover over, so I looked at a few examples online and it is able to work for a single image, however I would like for it to work with multiple images, these are the codes i found online thats work with a single image(credit to Jeff Yates for providing the solution)

**Xaml:**

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="growStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="testButton"
                    Duration="0:0:0.1"
                    By="20">
                </DoubleAnimation>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="testButton"
                    Duration="0:0:1"
                    By="-20">
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="shrinkStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="testButton"
                    Duration="0:0:1"
                    By="-20">
                </DoubleAnimation>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="testButton"
                    Duration="0:0:0.1"
                    By="20">
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button x:Name="testButton" Content="Test" Grid.Column="1" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="50">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class Page : UserControl
{
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.shrinkStoryboard.SkipToFill();
        this.growStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.growStoryboard.SkipToFill();
        this.shrinkStoryboard.Begin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an animation on ScaleTransform to do this like so:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverRectangleStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.1" From="1" To="1.1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
        </DoubleAnimation>
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.1" From="1" To="1.1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseLeaveRectangleStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.1" From="1.1" To="1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
        </DoubleAnimation>
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.1" From="1.1" To="1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

The code is for a rectangle but it's exactly the same.